# Should we have a "This is a polling question" close reason?

Tags: feature-request

Poll questions are closed as off topic for good reason.

Should "this is a poll question" be one of the predefined close reasons?

Possible side question - is there a limit to the number of predefined close reasons and/or a reason why we don't have more?

Comment: Why can't the "too broad" reason be used? "There are either too many possible answers..."

Comment: @ThomasOwens I don't think *too broad* is really adequate. [It's a hole in the new close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/what-close-reason-for-polling-questions).

Comment: Just use a comment to indicate that it's a poll; that gives you an opportunity to explain how the OP might edit and improve.

Comment: If you have a good suggestion for it, please add it to [How can I write a good custom close message](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/how-can-i-write-a-good-custom-close-message) (while it only has one answer so far, I do use that as a go to place for grabbing text for closing some questions).  Using a close message that indicates the polling question can help in formulating data for the "we should use this one" if/when we get more reasons... and if they are consistent, its all that much easier to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your side question - yes there is a limit to the number of custom close reasons. By default it's 3 so under the current scheme one of the other existing ones will have to be dropped.

If we can justify it we can get this number increased. So you'd have to show that there were just as many poll questions being closed as each of the other reasons.